# Wildfly 10.1 deserialize persisted session

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, marshalling, undertow

Given Wildfly 10.1 with session persistence configured as

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        ...
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config x-powered-by="false"/>
            <persistent-sessions path="ssn" relative-to="jboss.server.tmp.dir"/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        ...
    </subsystem>
```

After server shutdown I have a file named after my WAR file. Contents is somehow readable, I see a hashmap and session values inside.
I'd like to deserialize it.
After digging in Wildfly sources I've found the only class able to read session from file: *org.wildfly.extension.undertow.DiskBasedModularPersistentSessionManager*
But when I try to read file from src:

```
DiskBasedModularPersistentSessionManager sessionManager = new DiskBasedModularPersistentSessionManager("C:/tmp", "");
    sessionManager.start(null);
    sessionManager.baseDir = new File("c:/tmp"); 
    sessionManager.loadSerializedSessions("www.war");
```

It throws me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid byte
at org.jboss.marshalling.UTFUtils.readUTFBytes(UTFUtils.java:173)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readUTF(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1833)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:959)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1255)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.DiskBasedModularPersistentSessionManager.loadSerializedSessions(DiskBasedModularPersistentSessionManager.java:115)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.DiskBasedModularPersistentSessionManager.main(DiskBasedModularPersistentSessionManager.java:134)
```

After investigating the cause a little bit, I got an answer that this is some kind of mechanism to protect session migration from one major version to another. But in my case file is generated by same version of Wildfly and same lib versions.

- jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
- jboss-marshalling-1.4.11.Final.jar
- jboss-marshalling-river-1.4.11.Final.jar
- jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar
- undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar
- wildfly-undertow-10.1.0.Final.jar
- xnio-api-3.4.0.Final.jar

How can I read the session content?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why we are you trying to read the state of the sessions while the server is stopped?

Comment: Exploring an approach for exclusive case testing. Need to treat data captured from live run. So sessionIds at least is what I'm interested in.